# Can not get Android to create a folder in public external storage

Tags: android, file, save

I'm using Android Studio. I have my project set to require API version 11. The Emulator is set for Nexus 5 API23 (standard default settings).

I want to have my application write a simple text file to a location where I can pull the text files created onto my computer by plugging in with a USB cable. So it needs to be in the public external storage.

For whatever reason I can't get the code to create a folder for my text files to go into. I have paired my code down to this little nugget in a "Utilities" class I have:

```
public static boolean createTheDangFolder(Context c, String fileName, String body) {
    boolean saved = true;
    //File dir = new File(c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyCustomFolder");
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyCustomFolder");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        saved = dir.mkdirs();
    }
    return saved;
}
```

This function always returns false. If I trade comments on the "File" line it will return true but the commented out line is the app memory and I can't access the files via USB.

I have this line in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working and none of the other questions on the site have given me a solution that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed the permissions to external storage in KitKat.  You can only write to public folders (like downloads) and to your own app's private directory on external storage.

Comment: OK. So I changed the line to `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyCustomFolder");` but it's still not working. Is that not correct?

Comment: You'll have fewer issues if you don't fight Android, and just wrote them to type private directory on the sd card. Let the computer grab the from there

Comment: I would love to do that. The problem is that I can't see the files from the PC. I have a file viewer app on my phone and neither that or the PC via USB can see any files in the application directory.

Comment: This basically answers the question. I finally found a bunch of stuff that kind of let me do it. I have my program make a zip file of the files created and pass it to an email so you can get the files off the phone.